# How can i pass soap based XML as a body in ruby

Tags: ruby, soap

How can I pass this XML based body as input in RUBY

and do we need to install any gems for [this SOAPAction](http://abc.expenseanywhere.com/verifyLogin).

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
 <soap:Body>
   <verifyLogin xmlns="http://abc.expenseanywhere.com/">
   <AuthToken>
    <CorporateId>string</CorporateId>
    <Username>string</Username>
    <Password>string</Password>
  </AuthToken>
  </verifyLogin>
 </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

How can we pass complete XML as a body for ruby

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using http://savonrb.com/ - I have used this on several SOAP projects. Works great.